# Is it possible to use a getter as function parameter in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

I have a repetitive function like this :

```
repetitiveFunction(Type type) async* {
  yield* _recordCollectionQuery(type)
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) {
      final List<Record> records = snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => RecordDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
        .toList();
    // Here instead of using "record1.number", I want to use parameter like "record1.param"
    records.sort((record1, record2) => record2.number.compareTo(record1.number));
    return records;
  });
}
```

Here `Record` class is `freezed` data class. I have to use this function multiple times just changing `record.number`, here `number` is a getter of `Record` class. So can I use this getter as a function parameter?

Comment: You instead can pass different anonymous functions (e.g. `(record) => record.number`) for different members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use getters/setters as functions since the point of getters/setters is to be indistinguishable from member variables.

You instead can easily wrap the getters in anonymous functions (e.g. `(record) => record.number)`, and you then can supply different anonymous functions for different getters:

Here's a concrete example:

```dart
Stream<List<Record>> repetitiveFunction(
  List<Record> records,
  Comparable Function(Record) getComparableProperty,
) async* {
  yield* _recordCollectionQuery(type).snapshots().map((snapshot) {
    final List<Record> records = snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => RecordDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
        .toList();
    records.sort((record1, record2) => getComparableProperty(record2)
        .compareTo(getComparableProperty(record1)));
    return records;
  });
}
```